# How to add default values to a excel cell if user do not enter any values using Java?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am creating an excel sheet and writing data into it. And I will be reading that excel sheet in another program.

Now user can update the data present into the excel sheet. But if user removes present data and don't add any values in that cell then excel should add default values automatically. How can I do this in java?

I am posting a function which writes some values in the cell:

```
....
public static final void addVerificationTagData(Document d){
    String data[] = {"Y","Y","N","N","Y","Y","Y","Y","Y","Y","N","N","Y","Y","N","N","Y","Y","N","N","N","N"};
    //HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("EDR Raw Data");
    int personLen = d.getElementsByTagName("ecs:Person").getLength();
    for(int i = 1;i <= personLen;i++){
        int count = 0;
        for(int rn = 6;rn <= 27;rn++){
            Row r = sheet.getRow(rn);
            r.createCell(i).setCellValue(data[count]);
            //r.setRowStyle(cellStyle1);
            count++;
        }
        //sheet.autoSizeColumn(i);
    }
}
....
```

Is there any way to make the added values as default in case if user remove that value from cell and don't add anything?

Comment: Why do you need excel to set the default value as opposed to Java? In other words what's stopping you from adding a "if value is not set then use default" code in Java?

Comment: @gerrytan Thanks for your response!  the approach that u suggested is fine. I agree with you. But In my case I will access each row and cell in it group wise. So it's like checking everywhere if value is null then use default value. It will increase code. So I am adding a validation in excel itself that the length should not be zero. it will be good right?

Comment: I would suggest use pure java instead of adding some logic in excel. it will be more flexible and provides seperation between logic(java) and view(excel)